# How to use static embedded in grails 3.3.11?

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails3

I am not able to embed the Address into Person. Controller and views are auto generated. When I click on create I just get a blank page instead of proper UI of grails.

```
package trydemo

class Person {
String name
    Address address
    static  embedded = ['address']
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

```
package trydemo

class Address {
String city
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your domain classes look fine. The problem might be in scaffolded controller/views

Comment: @injecteer controller and views are auto generated

Answer (score 1):

> How to use static embedded in grails 3.3.11?

Assuming you are using GORM For Hibernate, the code you show is correct and is how you use `embedded` in Grails 3.3.11 (or any other version).

The effect of using `embedded` in that way is the `Address` properties will be stored in the same table as the `Person` properties so when you retrieve a `Person`, there is no join or foreign key involved.  All of the data to make a `Person` is in 1 row in 1 table.

Separate from that, you can organize your UI however you like.